# C programming by K&R what does the last k>0 do in the strindex function?

Tags: c

From ANSI C programming by K&R (page69), there is a strindex function, which will return a position of the fisrt search-for string in the source string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000 //max input length
int getline(char line[], int max);
int Strindex(char source[], char searchfor[]);
char pattern[] = "ould";

int main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int found = 0;

    while (getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
        if (Strindex(line, pattern) >= 0) {
            printf("%s", line);
            found++;
        }
    return found;
} // end of main function


int  getline(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;
    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int Strindex(char s[], char t[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = i, k = 0; s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
            ;
        if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0') //here is the k
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

My question is:

when `j = i, k = 0; s[j] != t[k]` (if the `t[]` and `s[]` are not empty strings), It seems `t[0]` will never get a value of `\0`? Then, what does this `k>0` do in the last if statement?: `if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')`

Comment: yes, seems that it's not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simply it is discarding all the `0` length targets. This is ***needed*** if you want to discard `0` length targets.(For this code. But there are better ways to do that).

Suppose `s` is `"CODE"` and `t` is an empty string containing `\0`. So in this case it enters for loop and the inner for loop breaks. And then `k=0` and if that condition (`k>0`) is omitted `if( t[k]=='\0')` is used then it will be true and it is returned. But again one may argue that it should match any indices if empty target is passed.

Comment: it would be better if this just checked if `t[0] == 0` and return `-1` right away then.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: It would be. And even better would be write the code altogether different way. I wonder they were writing it for an example not exact bulletproof code.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala.: To be honest I am pulling use of `k>0` and it seems that only in this case this serves the purpose. No matter the code cries for the situation to be handled different way. Adding that to answer was not part of question - that's why didn't add any alternative way. (there are many)

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right the `Strindex()` function checks if the string t is inside the string s.

So the `if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')` statement means that every character so far of the string t is the same with the string s and we reached the end of string t, so we got it mached and it returns the index of string s where the string t begins.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise if `t` is empty then this function will return 0 as a string index. It seems to be a waste to put this condition into cycle though.

Comment: Doesn't matter much, the string search algorithm itself is really naive and slow - and this slows it down only by a constant factor :D

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: If this was in the first edition of *The C Programming Language*, it was not really naïve. Boyer-Moore was published in 1977, by which time the book would have been in the publication process.

Comment: @VTT, the check is only done after `s[i] != t[k]` succeeds, so it is done only once, as you get out of the loop once `s[i] = '\0'` or `s[i] != t[k]`.  You do the test only once per function execution.  Do you really think K&R is bad written code? Think that pdp-11/40 virtual memory was only 64Kb wide and think about fitting all the unix utilities in the space of an old 8bit cpu.  The only time the test is done more than once is the case of passing a `""` target.  I think that is far less probable than making it once per `strindex` call.

Comment: @LuisColorado The check is performed on each iteration of outer loop. Even if `t` is empty and check is performed only once it still causes some overhead for starting a loop. Before asking about "bad written code" you need to define what "bad written code" actually is. Was writing something like this an improvement over some assembly or even hand-made binary? It definitely was. Is writing something like this acceptable today? It definitely is not.

Comment: Simply, bad written code is that that _appears superflous_ and invites you to take it off, and when you take it off, it doesn't make a difference.  `if (x == y) return true; else return false;` is bad written code (against `return x == y;`)  I invite you to see the whole V7 source code and you will see very well written code.  And you have the benefit of discussing this subject after more than 30 years this code was written.

Answer (score 0):

seems as it's not needed, but before touching any code from K&R, please, do full thoroughly checking.... probably it's needed. :) (edit:) indeed, that checks the case of calling strindex(3) with a null string `""` second parameter to fail, instead of succeeding at the first case.

the next code always succeeds at index `0` if you call:

```
strindex("something", "");
```

without that test.

Indeed, `i` maintains the source string index, `j` is the index of the being checked char, and `k` is the index in the second string of the checked char (the matched length).  the `k > 0` test makes it fail in case the second string index is `0` as then, the null string has been tried, and it always succeeds at length `0`.

The check of null string second parameter is more general, and as you can get that second string from the result of another calculation, it seems better to consider that case than to disallow it.